# Shortest path query returning empty list

Tags: netlogo

I have a network with 2851 nodes and 2887 links. The network represents railway lines in a city

I have been using the NW extension to identify the shortest path between some turtles.

However, for some queries, I am returning a blank list, rather than a legitimate response, or false (indicating a route does not exist).

```
observer> ask turtle 3 [show nw:path-to turtle 13]
(node 3): [(link 3 4) (link 4 5) (link 5 6) (link 6 7) (link 7 8) (link 8 9) (link 9 10) (link 10 11) (link 11 12) (link 12 13)]

observer> ask turtle 3 [show nw:path-to turtle 2851]
(node 3): []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works as designed. The [documentation of ***path*** primitives](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html#path-to-turtles-on-path-to-weighted-path-to-turtles-on-weighted-path-to) says:

> If no path exist between the source and the target turtles, all primitives will report an empty list.

On the other hand, ***distance*** primitives will report false if no path exists. As per the [documentation](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html#distance-to-weighted-distance-to):

> Finds the shortest path to the target turtle and reports the total distance for this path, or false if no path exists in the current context.

I will readily admit that this is not the most consistent design...

Comment: It does seem dodgy that an empty list might mean "no path", or it might mean "zero length path because source equals destination" `[nw:path-to turtle 3] of turtle 3`.

Comment: Thanks @Seth. Exactly Seth, that was my concern. I have such a possibility. That said, I did read the distance primitive and assume it functioned the same as the path primitive, thus my question.